# Emploi du mot « arabe »

Tags: expressions, politesse, culture

J'ai une petite question ;  on désigne souvent par le nom *arabe* des personnes issues du monde arabo-musulman. Cependant je me suis rendu compte qu'il était mal vu de l'employer, par exemple dans des phrases comme

- J'ai rencontré un arabe.
- Cette personne est arabe.
- Je suis un arabe.
- Est-ce que tu es arabe ?

J'aimerais savoir les contextes dans lesquels on peut employer ce mot/adjectif sans transmettre aucune idée de racisme, et s'il y a un autre mot qu'on pourrait utiliser à la place du mot *arabe*.

Comment: Cette question n'a vraiment pas sa place ici,il s'agit de sociologie, et de plus, elle est vraiment subjective "on ne peut pas dire...". Ah bon? Je ne suis pas au courant. Ces phrases sont totalement normales et je ne suis pas ce que vous entendez par "société"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic: sociology. And very subjective.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question, car c'est subjectif. Que veut dire "on ne peut pas le dire", que veut dire "en société".Le mot "arabe" qui est un mot qui a la connotation qu'on veut bien lui donner, mais désigne aussi une langue, et souvent employé pour désigner les maghrébins en France (génétiquement à tort d'ailleurs. Cette question appelle des relents racistes. Et est du domaine de la sociologie (à la limite de la socio-linguistique), je maintiens.

Comment: Avec le mot "race", la question était clairement irrecevable, mais maintenant que le mot "race" n'est plus là, et que la question affirme "qu'on ne peut pas" qualifier quelqu'un d'arabe, parce que ce serait une insulte, en "société", c'est tout aussi irrecevable. Mais, par contre, si la personne demandait une définition du mot "arabe", c'est recevable, mais hors sujet, car il suffit d'ouvrir un dictionnaire. Des questions sont fermées pour des faits beaucoup moins subjectifs que de dire "on ne peut pas faire ça en société".

Comment: La question est bien évidemment subjective: c’est précisément  sa raison d’être, à savoir la subjectivité de certains termes de la langue française et les contextes possibles de leur utilisation. Pour moi cette question n’est pas hors sujet, même si on peut imaginer des réponses qui pourraient l’être.

Comment: Je trouve que la question a parfaitement sa place ici.

Comment: @mouviciel > La langue francaise n'est pas plus subjective que l'anglaise. Les susceptibilités peuvent être heurtées dans toutes les langues. le mot "nigger" dans la bouche d'un afro-américain ou celle d'un américain blanc ne sera pas forcément accepté de la même manière.

Answer (score 5):

Il y a deux volets au problème : un souci de sens et un souci de connotation.

1) Le souci de sens, vient du fait que le mot *arabe* est très vague.

```
- J'ai un nouveau collègue, c'est un arabe. 
- Ah bon, il est saoudien ? 
- Non, tunisien je crois.
```

Dans ce cas, indépendamment des soucis éventuels de connotation, *maghrébin* sera plus précis. Ou tout simplement *tunisien*, tant qu'à faire... A mon travail, j'ai de nombreux collègues arabes, mais ça ne me viendrait pas à l'idée de les qualifier ainsi, car quand on connaît bien les gens, on se rend compte qu'un marocain et un tunisien sont aussi dissemblables qu'un suédois et un espagnol.

Autres exemples de confusion de sens, dire *arabe* alors qu'on voulait vraiment signifier *musulman*, ou dire *arabe* d'un algérien berbère et les berbères ne sont *pas* arabes (ou pire, appeler *arabe* un iranien ou un turc), etc.

2) Pour ce qui est du souci de connotation, comme le dit aussi mouviciel, c'est un problème de coller une étiquette sur quelqu'un, de le ranger dans une case. Quand on parle à quelqu'un d'autre, dire "J'ai rencontré un arabe" peut être ou peut ne pas être la meilleure manière de décrire la personne qu'on a rencontré. Si c'est la meilleure manière, ça ne me dérange pas que ce soit employé (mais d'autres personnes seraient peut-être outrés, on entre là dans le domaine du politiquement correct à outrance). Dans d'autres cas, le fait de choisir ce qualificatif en particulier a une signification.

```
- L'arabe est venu au magasin aujourd'hui. 
- Lequel ? 
- L'unijambiste.
```

Dans ce cas, ça ressemble à une connotation raciste, puique *unijambiste* est évidemment plus descriptif que *arabe*.

Imaginons que vous habitez un immeuble très cosmopolite, sur votre palier, il y a un appartement avec un arabe, un autre avec un chinois, un autre avec un indien, etc... dire "l'arabe est venu sonner à la porte pour me demander quelque chose", ça *pourrait* être factuel. Mais enfin, si vous connaissez le nom de la personne, c'est que vous auriez pu l'employer au lieu d'utiliser le qualificatif, et dans ce cas, il y aurait peut-être une connotation raciste à avoir dit "l'arabe est venu" plutôt que "Kader est venu". Mais c'est vraiment surtout une question de perception de la part de l'interlocuteur.

Answer (score 4):

En France, il est souvent délicat de mettre des étiquettes sur les gens sans qu’ils l’aient sollicité. Cela peut être perçu comme une forme de discrimination. Cette perception ne dépend même pas du mot utilisé. Dire *arabe* ou *beur* plutôt que *rebeuh*, *bougnoul* ou *magrébin* avec ou sans h n’enlève rien à la connotation discriminante. Parfois même un mot ou une expression qui semblent politiquement corrects, par exemple *gens du voyage* ou *roms* au lieu de *gitans* ou *romanichels*, sont tellement utilisés qu’ils en perdent la neutralité qu’on voulait leur donner.

Une seconde raison est que la personne qui attribue une étiquette peut tomber à côté et créer un embarras ou une méfiance. Tous les Kabyles n’aiment pas qu’on les range parmi les Arabes.

Enfin, personne ne se reconnaît dans une seule catégorie. Ce n’est pas parce que quelqu’un est en fauteuil roulant qu’il est *handicapé*. Il est en situation de handicap mais il est aussi beaucoup plus que cela, peut-être *arabe*, *femme*, *jeune*, *fumeur* et beaucoup d’autres choses encore.

Comment: Cela me rappelle quand j'étais dans une classe qui comptait 95 % de Noirs ou métisses des territoires d'outre-mer. Un prof parlait de "Blacks" et il s'est fait reprendre par des élèves de Guadeloupe qui lui reprochaient l'hypocrisie d'utiliser ce mot plutôt que "Noirs", a contrario les Réunionnais (beaucoup plus métissés et moins radicaux pour ce qui concerne les questions ethniques) comprenaient l'utilisation de ce terme et mettaient en avant que simplement parler de "Noirs" étaient parfois malheureusement associé à du racisme.

Comment: `était`* et non `étaient`

Answer (score 3):

> **P.S:** Votre question est subjective, et elle doit être migré ou fermé, mais puisque ce n'est pas le cas;
>
> Je répond a cette question en tant qu'un "Arabe"

l'Arabe est une langue comme toute les autres langues, telles que le Français, l'Anglais, etc... et encore c'est totalement différèrent de l'Islam qui est une religion comme le judaïsme, le christianisme, etc..., et encore c'est totalement différent de la race, puisque dans les pays Arabes on trouve plusieurs [races](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_humaine) qui sont des Arabes.

Il n'y a aucun problème d'utiliser le mot Arabe dans les phrases que tu as mentionnés:

- J'ai rencontré un arabe.
- Cette personne est arabe.
- Je suis un arabe.
- Est-ce que tu es arabe ?

Par contre l'utilisation du verlan du mot qui sera "rebeu" ou le verlan du verlan qui est "beur" "beurette" pour désigner un Arabe est dénoncé et sera signalé comme un racisme "décomplexé" comme le journal "Le Parisien" dans l'article du [12 Avril 2018](https://www.h24info.ma/videos/h24-tv/telephone-arabe-arrive-titre-choc-parisien/) (L'article ensuite a été modifié).

**Utiliser le sans transmettre aucune idée de racisme?**

C'est un mot qui signifie une langue parlé tout court, il ne faut jamais sentir qu'il y a du racisme lorsque on l'utilise. je vis en Algérie et je ne connais pas vraiment les problèmes intracommunautaire en France ou ailleurs, mais je te conseille d'éviter l'utilisation de dictionnaire d'argot (tous les synonymes sont des termes racistes de plusieurs point de vues "religion, couleur, histoire, langue...").

**Y-a-t-il un autre mot qu'on utiliser à la place du mot Arabe?**

Oui et Non, L'Arabe est l'une des langues sémitiques, on peut utilisé le terme "Sémite" en tant que synonyme, mais là on a un groupe de plusieurs langues telles que l'hébreu et l'araméen, mais Arabe désigne quelqu'un qui parle uniquement la langue [Arabe Standard Moderne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabe_standard_moderne) tout simplement.

Comment: Intéressant d'avoir cet éclairage de la part d'un algérien. A ce que vous dites, en Algérie ce serait différent, mais à mon avis, en France, dire de quelqu'un qu'il est "arabe" ne voudra jamais dire qu'il parle arabe, mais qu'il est "de race arabe" (sans m'avancer sur la pertinence du concept de race). Pour "qui parle arabe" on emploierait sans doute "arabophone", même si ce mot est d'un registre un peu soutenu.

Comment: @Steph La question avait été fermée au départ à cause de l'emploi du mot "race" qui en France ne s'emploie pas. On ne parle pas de race pour les humains mais uniquement pour les animaux. Même parler de [race humaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_humaine#Utilisation) est fortement déconseillé en France parce que [ce n'est pas un concept scientifique](https://www.nationalgeographic.fr/sciences/quand-la-genetique-mis-fin-au-concept-de-races-humaines). Je dis ça juste pour répondre à ta parenthèse, laquelle montre que tu es conscient du problème. Tu pourrais remplacer le mot par d'autres...

Comment: La plupart des questions de langue sont subjectives, ce n'est pas un problème. Ce qui serait un problème ce serait d'avoir des partis pris vis à vis de tel ou tel groupe humain. Ta réponse me semble appropriée.

Answer (score 1):

En fait tout dépend du contexte, si tu dis `j'ai un collègue arabe`, que veux-tu dire en fait ? Quelle information doit-on déduire de ce descriptif très vague, qui regroupe beaucoup de personnes différentes, mais que tu donnes comme s'il devait signifier quelque chose de précis ?

Je pense qu'en France le terme est perçu sur le même plan que les couleurs de peau, donc on pourrait comparer avec `j'ai un collègue noir`. À moins d'un contexte particulier (exemple : vous parlez du blanchiment chimique de la peau chez les Noirs), cette information semble à la fois trop vague pour être pertinente mais trop précise pour être innocente (sinon pourquoi même le mentionner ?).

Maintenant, il ne faut pas être dupe sur l'aspect sociologique, ce n'est pas qu'une question de vocabulaire pur, et dès qu'on tente de généraliser mon explication, on voit que la réalité ne colle pas. Les phrases suivantes semblent-elles toutes "un peu racistes" ou alors certaines moins, voire pas du tout ?

> J'ai un nouveau collègue, il est noir.
>
> J'ai un nouveau collègue, il est blanc.
>
> J'ai un nouveau collègue, il est arabe.
>
> J'ai un nouveau collègue, il est asiatique.1

M'est avis que les exemples avec `blanc` et `asiatique` ne semblent pas du tout déplacés, contrairement aux autres.

Pour rebondir sur le message de M. Abdelhafid, lui, Algérien de nationalité, entend `rebeu`, `beur` et compagnie comme des termes racistes, alors qu'ils sont généralement employés en France par peur d'utiliser le mot `arabe` et de passer pour un raciste, à tel point que je me suis déjà fait reprendre pour avoir dit `noir` "au lieu de" `black`. Mais j'ai aussi vu des Noirs reprendre quelqu'un pour l'exact inverse, car ils jugeaient que l'emploie de `black` traduisaient un genre de racisme.

---

1. dire `jaune` serait considéré comme totalement raciste, bien qu'en réalité `asiatique` me paraisse encore plus raciste, car on n'imagine mal quelqu'un employer ce mot pour parler indifféremment d'un Pakistanais ou d'un Japonais, par exemple dans une phrase comme `les Asiatiques sont des peuples encore très attachés à une philosophie millénaire`, on imagine tous des Asiatiques de l'Est avec le teint plutôt pâle et les yeux bridés. On ne parlera évidemment pas des gens qui emploient `chinois` pour tout ce qui correspond à cette description.

Answer (score -3):

Indépendamment de toute circonstance, JE, MOI, sujet ai absolument **tous** les **droits** de **me** dire comme je veux (et que ce soit juste ou non, vrai ou faux, pertinent ou non) =>

*Je suis un arabe ( noir / imbécile / misérable / intellectuel / bourgeois / gentil garçon / bibliophile / supporter de l'OL et du bon goût / érudit / cerveau-choc / admirateur de Nietzsche et de Jean-Michel Aulas...)* ne porte, en soi, strictement aucune connotation particulière **autre** que celle que **JE** mets.
L'interlocuteur pourra, tout au plus remettre en question votre... conscience de vous... ou... votre à propos ;-)

La perception des autres tournures sera effectivement fonction du contexte et surtout des aprioris des interlocuteurs.
Ainsi si je prononce les trois autres phrases à quelqu'un qui a un apriori négatif sur le sujet... je te laisse conclure!

Mais... il en irait identiquement avec n'importe quel autre substantif!

Va au stade vélodrome et demande à un Marseillais s'il est parisien, va dire à un ascète que tu as rencontré un gourmand, et va dire à un nihiliste que tu as rencontré un dieu...

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Après, dire quels aprioris particuliers sont le fait de quels contextes particuliers dépasse de loin la langue française. (Si même cela a jamais eu quoi que ce soit à voir avec)</sup>